Issue with Laravel Sanctum API and Vue client
When I try to login or register, I get this:
GET https://envios.uvpfernandarivera.cloud/api/auth/sanctum/csrf-cookie 404 (Not Found)

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <Login onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {__v_skip: true} > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

I can successfully login and perform the login in Postman.
I want to be able to access my local client and then upload it to Hostinger.

Did you look at how to set up CSRF?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
